# How to write data to open Libreoffce spreadsheet .xlsx file with xlwings and python from incoming webhook

Tags: python, json, webhooks, export-to-excel, xlwings

Using django to receive webhooks. No issue there. Trying to update cells in a working .xlsx spreadsheet on linux mint (using Libreoffice) from the webhook message data. Once the webhook comes in, nothing happens with the spreadsheet. I have tried to re-code this 100 times so I likely have extra code that is not needed or misplaced. Plus this is a combo of numerous code examples I have found on github. Not sure if there is something different necessary for Libreoffice .xlsx files.

Anyone want to look at my code and give me an assist?
```

````
```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods
from django.template import RequestContext
import json, config, logbot, os
import xlwings as xw



@csrf_exempt 

def home(request):
    data = {'name' : 'Hello'}
    data = json.dumps(data)
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')


def tradingview_webhook(request):

     logbot.logs("========= STRATEGY =========")

     data = json.loads(request.data)

     webhook_passphrase = os.environ.get('WEBHOOK_PASSPHRASE', config.WEBHOOK_PASSPHRASE)

     if 'passphrase' not in data.keys():
         logbot.logs(">>> /!\ No passphrase entered", True)
         return {
               "success": False,
               "message": "no passphrase entered"
    }

     if data['passphrase'] != webhook_passphrase:
         logbot.logs(">>> /!\ Invalid passphrase", True)
         return {
              "success": False,
              "message": "invalid passphrase"
    }

#   ALERT MESSAGE CONDITIONS
def orders(request):
payload = json.loads(request.data)
wb = xw.Book(r'/home/tester.xlsx')
sht1 = wb.sheets["Sheet1"],


if payload['message'] == 'entry':
    logbot.logs(">>> Order message : 'entry'")
    sht1.range('A1').value= "YES",
    sht1.range('A5').value= "NO"
    wb.save(r'/home/tester.xlsx')
    

elif payload['message'] == 'exit':
    logbot.logs(">>> Order message : 'exit'")
    sht1.range('A1').value= "NO",
    sht1.range('A5').value= "YES"
    wb.save(r'/home/tester.xlsx')
    

elif payload['message'][-9:] == 'reverse':
    logbot.logs(">>> Order message : 'reverse'")
    sht1.range('A1').value= "NO",
    sht1.range('A5').value= "NO"
    wb.save(r'/home/tester.xlsx')
    

else:
    logbot.logs(f">>> Order message : '{payload['message']}'")

return {
    "message": payload['message']
}





```

```
````

Webhook using ngrok
Read webhook data
Edit open excel workbook cells

Thats it. No API use or l/p configs needed.

Webhooks are fine. Excel does not update.

Answer (score 0):

If you use xlwings on Linux like this `xw.Book("file.xlsx")`, you should get the an error message (tested with xlwings 0.28.3).

xlwings on Linux is only works in either the read mode (see https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/reader.html):

```
xw.Book("myfile.xlsx", mode="r")
```

or as server backend for xlwings Server:

```
xw.Book(json=json.loads(request.data))
```

See https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/remote_interpreter.html.

It does, however, not support Libreoffice.